# File read from string in JS

Tags: javascript

I downloaded this string and saved it to my hard drive - [Link](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/6/input) .

When I try to open this file, the opening works ok, but when I try to split this into an array the data remains as a string. How can I split this into an array?

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('D:/day 6.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var array = data.split(' ');
    console.log(array);
});
```

**Edit:**

Someone asked for the input outside the file I was using. I'll post it, but I'm not sure that this will be formatted the same as the file I was working on.

```
11  11  13  7   0   15  5   5   4   4   1   1   7   1   15  11
```

Comment: `data` in the function is going to be an input buffer, if I am not mistaken. try calling it like `data.toString().split(' ')` and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: could you include in the post the string content you received from that url?  I get "Puzzle inputs differ by user.  Please log in to get your puzzle input."

Comment: @jhecht. That did it!. I also had to add a '\t'. If you put your answer below I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Go ahead and mark the answer that's there as they already wrote it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the return value differs going to be an input buffer so can use the `toString()` function for convert it to string.

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('D:/day 6.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var array = data.toString().split(' ');
    console.log(array);
});
```